# MVC iOS breakout game design

Tags: model-view-controller

I have the following models in my breakout like game:

- Ball.h
- Block.m
- GamePlay.m
- Paddle.h
- Paddle.m

I also have the following views:

- BallView
- BlockVIew
- PaddleView

My question is, when I change a property in the model, I have to change the property in the view also. For example:

Ball Model:

```
@interface Ball : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *radius;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *xSpeed;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *ySpeed;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *xDirection;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *yDirection;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint location;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *color;
@end
```

Ball View:

```
@interface BallView : UIView
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIColor *color;
@property (nonatomic) int radius;
@end
```

When the model has its properties changed, I have such as location, or color. I have to update these same properties in the view. Should I NOT track location and color in my model?

Answer (score 0):

I think the main point in MVC is maintainability over time. If you decide you need an entirely different view of your game tomorrow, the model code can stay the same, so you can focus on modifying just the view part.

Also, if you know you need some data about the game's state, you know where you can find it - in the model. For example, you might want to transmit the ball's location over the internet to your friend, if he is interested in watching you breaking blocks.

As you can probably guess from the last two paragraphs, you should indeed store and update the location and color of the ball in the model. The view shouldn't be the owner of app state.